How to understand this "simple" reasoning about the least action principle?
I watched this video on the principle of least action and at around minute 11:20 there is a derivation that I do not understand.
I actually do understand why the Euler-Lagrange equations are derived in general, I just do not understand this particular derivation.
He considers the simple Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
L(x,\dot{x}) = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-U(x)
\end{equation}
and then proceeds to consider a variation of the form
\begin{equation}
\tilde{x}(t) := x(t) + \varepsilon(t)
\end{equation}
Next, he states that
\begin{equation}
dL = m\dot{x}\dot{\varepsilon}-U'(x)\varepsilon
\end{equation}
I do not mathematically understand why, as he states, "the change in $\dot{x}$ is $\dot{\varepsilon}$". I can understand it as a gut feeling, since $\tilde{x}-x=\varepsilon$, but not formally.
Trying to be more formal, we have
\begin{equation}
dL(\tilde{x},\dot{\tilde{x}}) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial\tilde{x}}d\tilde{x} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\tilde{x}}} d\dot{\tilde{x}}=-U'(\tilde{x})\ d\tilde{x}+m\dot{\tilde{x}}\ d\dot{\tilde{x}}
\end{equation}
But this seems to me a dead end, I do not know how to go on from here. I am unable to make a formal derivation of this, and I don't know why.
Isn't it true that $d\tilde{x} = dx+d\varepsilon$? And that $d\dot{\tilde{x}}=d\dot{x}+d\dot{\varepsilon}$?
The derivation I know (and understand) of the Euler-Lagrange equations considers a variation of the form
\begin{equation}
\tilde{x}(t):=x(t)+\lambda\varepsilon(t)
\end{equation}
and then one could take the actual derivative of the action functional with respect to $\lambda$, and all made perfect sense. I don't see how to connect the dots in the seemingly easier, but messy (for me), former situation.

The variation of $\tilde{x}(t)$:
$$\tilde{x}(t) = x(t) + \epsilon(t)$$
has this derivative with respect to time: $$\frac{d \tilde{x}(t)}{dt} = \dot{x}(t) + \dot{\epsilon}(t)$$
He explains this part around 7 mins with a bit of abuse of notation
The perturbed version of the Lagrangian
$$L(x + \epsilon) $$
Should perhaps be written:
$$L(\tilde{x}, \dot{\tilde{x}}) = \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{x}(t) + \dot{\epsilon}(t))^2 - U(x(t) + \epsilon(t)) $$
$$L(\tilde{x}, \dot{\tilde{x}}) =  \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{x}(t)^2 + 2\dot{x}(t)\dot{\epsilon}(t)  + \dot{\epsilon}(t)^2) - U(x(t) + \epsilon(t))$$
$$L(\tilde{x}, \dot{\tilde{x}}) =  \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}(t)^2 + m\dot{x}(t)\dot{\epsilon}(t) + \frac{1}{2}m \dot{\epsilon}(t)^2 - (U(x(t)) + \dot{U}(t)\epsilon(t))$$
We can assume that $\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\epsilon}^2$ is 0 because we only care about the leading order here. The same goes for $U(x(t) + \epsilon(t)) $.
$$dL = L(\tilde{x}, \dot{\tilde{x}}) - L(x, \dot{x}) = m \dot{x} \dot{\epsilon }- \dot{U}\epsilon$$

I feel that the issue is exactly the (possible?) abuse of notation of the Taylor expansion of $U(x(t)+\varepsilon(t))$ as $U(x(t))+\dot{U}(x(t))\varepsilon(t)$.

If for simplicity we have a Lagangian with no potential, shouldn't it be $dL = \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\tilde x}}\ d\dot{\tilde{x}} = m\dot{\tilde{x}} \ (d \dot{x}+d\dot{\varepsilon})$?

I'm now confused myself. I cannot arrive to the answer from your method either

$x$ is fixed so $d\dot{x}$ is zero. The point of introducing $\epsilon$ is to isolate all variations in the form of an additive perturbation
